# SonicWall SRA1600 & NSA2600 Configuration headaches

Tags: vpn, web-server, sonicwall

I am working in a site in where the old admins were, well lets just say free reign.  This sounds nice but it's taken me a good amount of time to get up and walking enough where I own this site now buy re-configuring a few things to make it work, but I've left the brains mostly alone till now.

I am attempting to set up a generic www server right now.

Here is the setup, we have a business account though Comcast (not my idea), and it has a static IP.  When I attempt to follow the manual as SonicWall suggests to open a port though the NSA, and I did... I also made it a high priority so nothing else would go first.

the WWW server is 10.9.1.200, and I have the 80 port directed straight to that IP address.

I am wondering, am I missing something?

The last thing I attempted was this:

https://support.sonicwall.com/kb/sw7979

When I attempt to follow the instructions and do as it says, the page on the website is a login for the VPN... not the web page as it should be by now.

So I am stuck, if anyone can help get me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Realistically this will be only temporary, for I am going to Sophos and what takes three pieces of hardware to do, this only takes one.

Comment: you need NAT and an access rule. Do you have both?

Comment: Yes, both.  Actually, I was able to have the company agree to tare down the network backend and go with Sophos.